# Get category meta tags via REST API

Tags: magento2, rest-api

How do I get meta title, meta description and optional keywords from category via the REST API in Magento 2.2?

```
https://localhost/rest/V1/categories/123

https://localhost/rest/V1/categories/list?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=name&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=news&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][conditionType]=eq
```

Above API calls Will get me the category just without the fields I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just tested it and

```
GET /V1/categories/:categoryId
```

works just fine. One note it will not display attribute if there are no values, it appears for me as soon as I added it in the admin panel

[image]

Comment: Aaahh.. It turned out that I pulled data from the wrong store. I got multiple stores in my Magento shop. Also I didn't know that if e.g. meta_title is empty it will not show up.